# Configurar plugin NBAndroid-v2 en Netbeans 8.2

Tags: android, netbeans-8.2, gradle

Buen día, por razones laborales debo empezar a trabajar en un proyecto de android sobre el IDE NetBeans, investigando encontré que se debe instalar el plugin NBAndroid, el cual según lo que leí ya no esta disponible oficialmente aunque hay un repositorio en github donde se le esta dando soporte.

https://github.com/NBANDROIDTEAM/NBANDROID-V2

El problema es que el procedimiento que describen para instalar el plugin es un poco complejo, lo único que he podido hacer es instalar el plugin "Gradle support", les pido por favor me den una mano de como debo proseguir, estas son las instrucciones que aparecen en GitHub, gracias de antemano

How to run/debug this plugin from NetBeans
This plugin depends on Gradle Support plugin. You need to add it to platform folder.

-Install Gradle Support plugin to NetBeans

-Make copy of NetBeans directory

-Copy .netbeans/NB_Version/modules/org-netbeans-gradle-project.jar to NB_COPY/extide/modules/

-Copy .netbeans/NB_Version/modules/ext folder to NB_COPY/extide/modules/

-Copy .netbeans/NB_Version/update_tracking/org-netbeans-modules-options-java.xml to NB_COPY/extide/update_tracking/

-Copy .netbeans/NB_Version/config/Modules/org-netbeans-gradle-project.xml to NB_COPY/extide/config/Modules/
Add new Profile to pom.xml
        
        
            your_name-NB82
            
                true
            
            
                
                    
                        org.codehaus.mojo
                        nbm-maven-plugin
                        3.13
                        true
                        
                            FULL_PATH_TO_NB_COPY
                            FULL_PATH_TO_CUSTOM_USER_DIR
                        
                    
                
            
            
                RELEASE82
                asm-all-5.0.1
            
        
        ...
    
And finally select your profile

Answer (score 1):

Crea un nuevo centro de actualización e instala el complemento..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]